# Where to store web custom control data

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am creating a custom control extending WebControl. This web control allows the consumer to define a collection of columns in markup, something like this:

```
<Custom:CustomGrid>
<Columns>
    <Custom:DataColumn HeaderText="FirstName" />
    <Custom:DataColumn HeaderText="LastName" />
</Columns>
```

and put an IEnumerable in a DataSource property and this is rendered out to a table.
This control also allows paging. The IEnumerable in DataSource is the full list, and I display a page of the list at a time. I am already saving the current page, number of rows per page, etc. to viewstate. Should I also put the full list in viewstate? Maybe session? 
This list can become a bit hefty. Maybe save in session with a random key, which is saved in viewstate?
What is the best practice here?

**Edit:** I don't think it's right to impose that all types in the IEnumerable be serializable. Is that fair? So do I need to copy the data source to some other data structure for serialization?

**Edit 2:** Even if I do use a base control instead of implementing RenderChildControls I will need to implement CreateChildControls, but I will still need to persist the data somewhere, or did I miss the point of the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, not all `IEnumerable` instances will be serializable.

If the query is cheap to run I wouldn't persist the whole data set but just run the query again for a different page or a change in the sort order.

If you put the data in viewstate you'll end up with huge pages.  Session state might be acceptable if you don't have many users, but large data sets with lots of users won't scale well.  What if I bind a million rows to your control?  Or what if your control was used in a repeater and shown 100 times on a page?

Are you sure you need to persist the data?  This isn't premature optimisation is it?

Remember that your control is a UI component.  The viewstate should hold enough information to maintain the UI state as it is.  A change in state (e.g.: switching to a different page of results) is something for which your control should pass responsibility to the data source.

Take a look at good old `GridView`.  It displays what you give it and remembers that.  If you're using paging then it raises an event to say "the user has changed page; give me page x of data".  For me, that's the best practice for a UI control.

Comment: That is more or less what I ended up doing. Since the data sets are not very large, I just pass the responsibility of setting the DataSource property on each postback to the consuming page and I store in ViewState only what I need to bring the DataSource to its previous state.

Answer (score 0):

For implementing databound control it is better to use base class which was designed to perform such task. For example in ASP.NET exist CompositeDataboundControl which can be used as a base class to implement custom data bound controls. I can advice to review the following Dino Esposito article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx.

Basically if you create control like ASP.NET gridview then it is store values in viewstate. To be more clear it is create number of the DataRow controls which saved assigned values in viewstate. During postback it recreates the same number of rows and values are restored from viewstate. If you will save only datasource for example in session without using viewstate then you will need to redatabind data to your grid during every postback. So, if you create Server control similar to gridview then approach described in the Dino Esposito post will be very helpful because it shows how to create control similar to ASP.NET Server GridView control.

Comment: Well most of my controls are manually rendered (and are pure HTML, not server controls), so I can't count on the controls to retain their own viewstate.